# Python Calculating Days off from a Rotating Work Shift

Tags: python, calendar, schedule

> I'm new to python, and I can't figure out any strategy or existing
>   module that would solve this problem.  I would like to make a simple
>   program that would return if a given day in the future would be a day
>   off or not based on the following schedule (actual schedule for this
>   week of July 2018):
>
> ```
> Week 1: 1:Sun:off 2:Mon   3:Tues   4:Wed:off   5:Thur   6:Fri   7:Sat
>
> Week 2: 8:Sun:  9:Mon:off 10:Tues  11:Wed     12:Thur  13:Fri  14:Sat:off
>
> Week 3:15:Sun:off  16:Mon   17:Tues  18:Wed:off  19:Thur  20:Fri  21:Sat 
>
> Week 4:22:Sun 23:Mon:off   24:Tues  25:Wed     26:Thur  27:Fri  28:Sat:off
> ```

```
import datetime

sched1 = {'Mon':'working','Tues':'working','Wed':'off','Thur':'working','Fri':'working','Sat':'working','Sun':'off'}
sched2 = {'Mon':'off','Tues':'working','Wed':'working','Thur':'working','Fri':'working','Sat':'off','Sun':'working'}

pickdate1 = int(input("Enter a date in the year (YYYY)): "))
pickdate2 = int(input("Enter a date in the year (MM): "))
pickdate3 = int(input("Enter a date in the year (DD): "))


date = datetime.date(pickdate1,pickdate2,pickdate3)
weekno = datetime.date(pickdate1,pickdate2,pickdate3).isocalendar()[1]
weekday = datetime.date.isoweekday(date)

if weekno % 2 == 0:
    print (sched2[weekday])

elif weekno % 2 != 0:
    print (sched1[weekday])
```

Comment: These data are in a list? If yes, what exactly are the elements?

Comment: It's not clear to me from the sample what the pattern is. Could you describe it? Also please post any code you've written to try to solve this problem.

Comment: looks like it alternates between sun/wed and mon/sat off

Comment: what happens if it goes to 29/30/31 (i.e., a new month?

Comment: Scott mentioned the pattern.  I have no code yet because I can't fathom how to begin.  The pattern would continue  with every other wednesday off, every other monday off, and every other Sat/Sun off with the pattern mentioned in the example.

Comment: I've looked into a few modules already like schedule, sched, timeboard, and pyschedule.  None of them look to be what I need.

Comment: If the pattern above never changes then you could use the "week number" that can be found in the tuple returned from:  `datetime.date(year, mo, day).isocalendar()`.  Then if that week number is even (or odd, whichever works in your case) then that points to the schedule for that week.

Comment: i updated the code, but i can't figure out how to associate and recall the day with the date (i.e. Sunday -> 1st)

Comment: I updated the code to build upon my earlier attempt: making the dictionary match the isoweekday format so that an integer from Monday returns 1 and so on.  However I get a KeyError of 3 for today's date, which should be right...Wednesday (or 3).

Comment: I just had to associate the key to the integer returned and everything is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

This produces a list of weekly schedules. Each weekly schedule is a list starting from Monday and going through Sunday. The choice of monday through sunday is just to align with Python's order of day of week in the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) and [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) modules.

```
weeks = []
num_weeks = 4 # how many weeks to schedule
days_off = [
    (2, 6),   # sunday and wednesday
    (0, 5),   # monday and saturday
]

for week in range(num_weeks):
    days_off_this_week = days_off[week % len(days_off)]
    weeks.append([bool(i not in days_off_this_week) for i in range(7)])
```

The key here is using the `%` operator (`week % len(days_off)`), rather than `//` to determine which week's schedule we should use. Because we use `len(days_off)` we can make our 2 week rotation a 3 or 4 week rotation by simply adding an entry to `days_off`, and the calendar will still work.

Storing the day of week as an integer and the on/off as a boolean affords us a lot of flexibility in how we later organize this information for display. We can print schedules easily using the calendar module:

```
import calendar
from collections import OrderedDict
cal = calendar.Calendar(calendar.SUNDAY)

for week in weeks:
    print(OrderedDict([(calendar.day_abbr[i], ("On" if week[i] else "Off")) for i in cal.iterweekdays()]))
```

To change the first weekday per week in our display, we just pass a different day of the week to `calendar.Calendar`, (e.g. `calendar.Calendar(calendar.MONDAY)`).

This doesn't factor in the actual date, but I'm happy to add that if it's useful.

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime

sched1 = {'Mon':'working','Tues':'working','Wed':'off','Thur':'working','Fri':'working','Sat':'working','Sun':'off'}
sched2 = {'Mon':'off','Tues':'working','Wed':'working','Thur':'working','Fri':'working','Sat':'off','Sun':'working'}

pickdate1 = int(input("Enter a date in the year (YYYY)): "))
pickdate2 = int(input("Enter a date in the year (MM): "))
pickdate3 = int(input("Enter a date in the year (DD): "))


date = datetime.date(pickdate1,pickdate2,pickdate3)
weekno = datetime.date(pickdate1,pickdate2,pickdate3).isocalendar()[1]
weekday = datetime.date.isoweekday(date)


if weekno % 2 == 0:
    if weekday == 1:
        print ("You are: %s" % (sched2['Mon']))
    elif weekday == 2:
        print ("You are: %s" % (sched2['Tues']))
    elif weekday == 3:
        print ("You are: %s" % (sched2['Wed']))
    elif weekday == 4:
        print ("You are: %s" %  (sched2['Thur']))
    elif weekday == 5:
        print ("You are: %s" %  (sched2['Fri']))
    elif weekday == 6:
        print ("You are: %s" %  (sched2['Sat']))
    elif weekday == 7:
        print ("You are: %s" %  (sched2['Sun']))
elif weekno % 2 != 0:
    if weekday == 1:
        print ("You are: %s" %  (sched1['Mon']))
    elif weekday == 2:
        print ("You are: %s" %  (sched1['Tues']))
    elif weekday == 3:
        print ("You are: %s" %  (sched1['Wed']))
    elif weekday == 4:
        print ("You are: %s" %  (sched1['Thur']))
    elif weekday == 5:
        print ("You are: %s" %  (sched1['Fri']))
    elif weekday == 6:
        print ("You are: %s" %  (sched1['Sat']))
    elif weekday == 7:
        print ("You are: %s" %  (sched1['Sun']))
```